# JS add +10 then sort DIV

Tags: javascript

**GOAL script returns 20,13,12,11**

Hi I am trying to make these two operations into a single operation on Load.
when loaded the page returns **3,2,10,1**
so I have added a button to trigger a +10 function.
which returns **13,12,20,11**

Both these functions work independently, however i need the the entire thing to work together **so that it returns 20,13,12,11** on load

I don't want any buttons>>>>

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--CSS-->
 <style type="text/css">
    .box {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
}
  </style>
  <!--JAVASCRIPT-->
  <!-- (A) ADDS +10 to div No-->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#increase").click(function(event){     
    $("div.box").each(function(idx,elem){
      $(this).text( parseInt($(this).text(),10) +10 );
    });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
  <div id="containerSort">
  <!-- (B) SORTS div -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
var $divs = $("div.box");

$( "#numBnt" ).one("load", function() {
console.log('loaded')
var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).find("h7").text() < $(b).find("h7").text();
});
$("#containerSort").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
}); 
 </script>
<!--HTML-->
<div class="box"><h7>1</h7></div>
<div class="box"><h7>2</h7></div>
<div class="box"><h7>3</h7></div>
<div class="box"><h7>10</h7></div>

<img src="http://myscot.com/ImagesMain/myscotLogoResp120.jpg" id="numBnt"/>
</div>

<button id="increase">+10</button>
```

window.addEventListener("load", function(){...}) how would I combine the 2 functions to the event listener?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: GOAL script returns 20,13,12,11

Comment: Note: `$(function(){})` and `$(document).ready()` are same. First approach is a shorthand for second. Also if you wish to execute a function, just do `window.addEventListener("load", function(){...})` [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load)

Comment: Im trying to get 4 DIVs to load in order Highest to lowest

Comment: So in I understand right, you want to perform addition and then perform sort them. Am I right?

Comment: Header tags only go from `<h1>` to `<h6>`, there is no such thing as `<h7>`.

Comment: h7 is working fine for this

Comment: window.addEventListener("load", function(){...}) how would I combine the 2 functions to the event listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve your problem

- Call button's click event on page load.
- Create a function which will wrap everything and assign it as eventListener.

**Note:**

- `$(function(){})` is a short hand for `$(document).ready()` and its a bad practice to have multiple *document.ready* functions.
- H7 is not a valid header tag as mentioned by [@Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol). Browser might consider it as a custom element and process similar to `span` tag. (This is just a guess).
- Below code:

```js
$("div.box").each(function(idx, elem) {
  $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 10);
});
```

this will make multiple DOM operation. Its bad practice to manipulate DOM in a loop.

Following is a sample code. Also I have updated your code a bit.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/4nL5eqha/1/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#increase").trigger("click");
});

$("#increase").click(function() {
  var valArr = getValues();
  valArr = addNumber(valArr);
  valArr = sortValues(valArr);
  createAndRenderHTML(valArr, "#containerSort");
});

function getValues() {
  var returnArray = [];
  $("div.box").each(function(id, el) {
    returnArray.push(parseInt($(el).text(), 10));
  });
  return returnArray;
}

function addNumber(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10) + 10;
  });
}

function sortValues(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0
  });
}

function createAndRenderHTML(arr, el) {
  var _html = arr.map(function(item) {
    return "<div class='box'> <h7>" + item + "</h7></div>"
  }).join("");
  $(el).html(_html);
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerSort">
  <!--HTML-->
  <div class="box">
    <h7>1</h7>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h7>2</h7>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h7>3</h7>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h7>10</h7>
  </div>

  <img src="http://myscot.com/ImagesMain/myscotLogoResp120.jpg" id="numBnt" />
</div>

<button id="increase">+10</button>
```

Comment: I don't need the button EVER, it only has to happen on load.

Comment: Then remove eventListener and create a wrap function and use it.

Comment: EXCELLENT  I don't ever need a button, it only has to happen once on load

Comment: Create a function which will wrap everything and assign it as eventListener.

Comment: PLEASE REMOVE THE BUTTON, it was only for example, this function must work WITHOUT any thing being clicked

Comment: Rajesh, we are very close and thank you, but there will be NO BUTTON to click, on load only

Comment: @micalotl In the updated fiddle, remove the button's DOM and every reference from JS. Simple.

Comment: Rajesh for your help, I can work with this..... thank you, yes, H7 needs monitoring, cheers